# Función recursiva retorna nulo en segunda llamada

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy intentando crear una clase que capture un valor entero utilizando recursividad, cuando por primera vez se ejecuta y el valor es correcto, retorna el valor, pero, sino es correcto muestra el mensaje y se auto invoca, pero retorna el valor de Nulo. El código es el siguiente:
El archivo captura.py

```
class captura:

   def leerEntero( txt ):

      try:

         vr = int ( input(txt) )

         return vr

      except ValueError:

         print( "Error" )

         captura.leerEntero( txt )
```

En el archivo donde necesito capturar el valor en varias ocasiones, llamado:
leerCaptura.py

```
from captura import *

x = captura.leerEntero( "Ingrese un entero: ")

print( x )
```

Al ejecutar un valor correcto por primera vez:

```
Ingrese un entero: 36

36   #Todo correcto
```

Pero si se llega a cometer un error de valor:

```
Ingrese un entero: 3g   #Error para ser entero
Error

Ingrese un entero: 3  #Me vuelve a pedir el número, por recursividad, 

None  #pero me retorna
```

Les pido el favor si me pueden ayudar para solucionar este inconveniente
Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: En la última línea de la función `leerEntero` no tiene retorno, coloca `return captura.leerEntero( txt )`

Comment: Saludos Yussef, es correcta tu ayuda, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma que había probado y me funciono era:

```
class captura:

   def leerEntero( txt ) :

      vr = 0

      try:

         vr = int ( input(txt) )

      except ValueError:

         print( "Error" )

         vr = captura.leerEntero( txt )

      return vr
```

Muchas gracias Yussef